# Show value while typing but only take first 6 number only, and change order of number

Tags: php, jquery, html, autofill

I have 2 fields when I type in ID NO field (first six number is date of birth with `YYMMDDxxxxxx`, (always contains 12 number), the DOB field will auto filled, based on ID NO, but the value of DOB only contains first 6 number in ID NO field and the order will be `DDMMYY`.

**Example:**

> ID NO: **931121**091010 (YYMMDD)
>
> DOB  : **211193** (DDMMYY)

```js
var $dob = $("#dob");
   $("#id_no").keyup(function() {
   $dob.val(this.value);
   });
  $("#id_no").blur(function() {
    $dob.val(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
  <label>ID NO</label>
    <input type="text" name="id_no" id="id_no" class="form-control" onKeyPress="return 
       goodchars(event,'1234567890',this)" required="" value="">
  </div>
  <div>
  <label>DOB</label>
    <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" class="form-control" value="">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Sounds like a school exercise, would you post what you've tried?

Comment: yes chaska, i already updated what i've tried in snippet. i only can to copy all value to DOB field, but i cant figure out how to change the format while i typing

Answer (score 0):

See the live example below:

```js
var $dob = $("#dob");
$("#id_no").keyup(function() {
  var str = this.value;
  var strYYMMDD = str.substring(0, 6);
  if (str.length > 6) {
    var strDDMMYY = strYYMMDD.substring(4, 6) + strYYMMDD.substring(2, 4) + strYYMMDD.substring(0, 2);
    $dob.val(strDDMMYY);
  } else {
    $dob.val("");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    <label>ID NO</label>
    <input type="text" name="id_no" id="id_no" class="form-control" maxlength="12" onKeyPress="return 
       goodchars(event,'1234567890',this)" required="" value="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>DOB</label>
    <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" class="form-control" value="">
  </div>
</form>
```